# Can I be Miracast compatible with Wi-Fi dongle?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, miracast

I have a Windows 10 desktop with no Wi-Fi device, it is connected with an Ethernet cable. If I buy a Wi-Fi USB dongle, can my desktop be Miracast compatible?

Example of Wifi USB dongle I mean: https://www.amazon.ca/WISE-TIGER-Adapter-600Mbps-Wireless/dp/B01M0Q51UI/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=wireless+adapter&qid=1560831444&s=gateway&sr=8-1

Comment: WiFi is just part of the story. You can read e.g. [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/set-up-use-miracast-windows-10/amp) what else you need to check.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Yes, I see my TV in Devices and "Miracast: Available, with HDCP". So if I just buy a Wifi dongle, will my desktop be Miracast compatible?